# Dark/Mystery related cartoon with a blond protagonist

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I used to watch a cartoon when I was a kid, sometime during the the 2000s(?).

I remember that the story was pretty dark, or mystery related. The art style was something like *Batman: The Animated Series*. The protaganist was a boy, probably a teen or a guy in his early twenties at max. He had blonde hair, and usually was dressed in black clothes. I don't remember any details of the story, except that there was an organization/group of people chasing him for some reason.

I remember a scene in particular: the protagonist into some kind of mall/research building, jumping from the second floor with some kind of skylight above him, while shooting.

Comment: What about this show was science fiction or fantastical? They way you're describing it, it sounds like a straight up mystery show like Kouichi Zenigata

Comment: Science fiction, I think.

Comment: What about it was sci-fi? Can you think of even one thing that wasn't mundane/contemporary?

Comment: I'm not sure. But maybe it was alien related.

Comment: Gantz? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vPiCTBE9rRc

Comment: No, no. It wasn't an anime. It was something western.

Comment: Maybe a stretch, but: Jonny Quest? He is blonde and wears a black shirt, https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/150526174900-jonny-quest-0526-super-169.jpg

Comment: Late 90s? It could be, yes. No, it's not Jonny Quest.

Comment: Could also be the short Action-Man cartoon, except the mc was not blonde, but there was a bright blonde girl in there.

Answer (score 4):

Sci-Fi with a teen/Young adult jumping all over the place with a simplified, but notable art style? *could* be **Martin Mystery,** in some episodes: where as usually colorful, as seen below, Martin *would* where a black turtleneck under his colorful shirt when going into colder climates:

[image]

The general tone of the Sci-Fi based show was Spooky comedy. Could this be what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Could it be
"Real adventures of Johnny Quest"
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could it be Pirates of Dark Water?